# Extent Reports won't provide the report for me

Tags: c#, selenium, report, extentreports

I'm trying to provide a report for a simple QA Method but the code wont generate any report for me, please help!

```
namespace CasinoClubTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class CasinoTests
    {
        public ExtentReports extent;
        public ExtentTest test;


        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void StartReport()
        {
            extent = new ExtentReports();
            var htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("ReportLogin.html");
            extent.AttachReporter(htmlReporter);
        }
        [Test]
        public void OpenWebsite()
        {
            IWebDriver driver = null;
            try
            {
                test = extent.CreateTest("OpenWebsite").Info("Test Started");
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                driver.Url = "https://www.casinoclub.com";
                driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
                test.Log(Status.Info, "Chrome Browser Start");
                test.Log(Status.Info, "Chrome Browser Closed");
                driver.Quit();
                test.Log(Status.Pass, "Testing is done!");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public void EndReport()
        {            
            extent.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you check: https://speedupqa.wordpress.com/2017/05/04/generate-automation-test-report-using-extentreports-in-c/

Comment: Yes i did, my code is written according to the instructions there but it's not providing the report for some reason.

Comment: provide some information: error/stacktrace/expectation/current result ?!